# img insert into HTML from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to insert images into `<marquee>` from a js file. 
This is what my js file looks like?

```
function buildList() {
    var data= ['logo1.png', 'logo2.png', 'logo3.png'];

    //var data2 = [{2:"hello"},{3:"world"},{6:"PSI"},{4:"ali"},{7:"buck"},{1:"hello"},{8:"albert"},{5:"wow"}];
    var marquee = document.getElementsByTagName('marquee');

    for(var i in data) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {

            //var newListItem = ' ' + data[i] +  ' there should be an img coming in from an array here';

            return img;
        };

        img.src = data[i];
        marquee[0].innerHTML  +=  img ;
        //http:www.quackit.com/pix/milford_sound/milford_sound_t.jpg"alt="Milford Sound in New Zealand' "Width=80 Height=80" ' + img;
    }
}
```

However when I look at the developer console in chrome, I get no error messeges by inside the `marquee` it is giving me `[object HTML ImageElement]`... What am i doing wrong?

Comment: [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) (e.g., `marquee[0].appendChild(img)`)

Answer (score 2):

Use `appendChild` instead of setting the `innerHTML`

```
marquee[0].appendChild(img);
```

Comment: the thing is that this method does not allow for any space and text after the image goes in. So after the img is inserted, I also need to insert some text from another array.

Comment: @AliAslam,ok, why not create a new `div` or `p` element and use `appendChild`?

Comment: for text use marquee[0].innerHTML  += '<div>text</div>';

Comment: I solved it by creating a TextNode inside my for loop and then doing appendChild(textnode) after appendChild(img).